# Test application cannot find autowired bean in same project

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing

I have a jar file that is the persistence layer,  ad I just want to test the DAO that are simply autowired into other service layer clasees. But I want to test without any mocking or whatever.

I think this should be pretty simple.  I have this in my srs/test/java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan("com.xxxx")
public class ApplicationTester  {

@Autowired 
AplicationDocumentDao aplicationDocumentDao;

@Test
private void testAplicationDocumentDao() {
    aplicationDocumentDao.allForOrg(1);
}

}
```

All the DAO's are in the same projust under the usual /src/main/java

When I run the mvn to just run the tests like this:

```
  mvn -Dtest=ApplicationTester test
```

I get this error:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'xxx.test.ApplicationTester': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'aplicationDocumentDao'; 
 nested exception is 0rg.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'xxx.dao.AplicationDocumentDao' available: 
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Which means is can't find the Bean of course,  but i would think the @ComponentScan   would pick up add the Dao's.

How do I get this tester to find all my Dao's  (Which are all annotated with @Componenet)  and are picked up just fine in the rest for the application.

Any ideas?

** EDIT **
here is the DAO

```
 @Repository
 @Component
 public class AplicationDocumentDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

@Autowired
public void setJT(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
     setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
}

public List<ApplicationDocumentBean> allForOrg(int orgId) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ApplicationDocument WHERE organizationId = ?";
    return (List<ApplicationDocumentBean>) getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ApplicationDocumentBean>(ApplicationDocumentBean.class), orgId);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotate to your persistence layer class, for example: @Repository or @Component,like this :

```
@Repository
public interface OrderMapper {}
```